# Create dynamic tests with PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, dynamic

I am trying to write some dynamic tests in PHP.

The idea is that some parts of my code test themselves (based on annotations).

I have this working one way; my test class has a single method `testRun` and a dataProvider `testRunProvider` which tests each method in turn with a given set of data which is itself dynamically generated. This does work, however when a test fails its not very readable, as there is only one test with different data.

I've tried numerous combinations of creating tests and suites within a test which has a provider, which feeds it methods, which as far as I can figure should mean that for each method I test, I create a new suite of tests for it, which I then pass data too.

The closest Ive gotten is to get the name of a "new" test to show, but it never completes and the test runner doesnt recognise the new test in the total count.

Comment: Could you share [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that I was almost there - you can define a custom test suite by putting a static function called `suite` which takes as an argument the name of the suite.

Where I was going wrong is I was not returning the suite it creates.